# scala copy keys and values from a map to separate lists in the same order

Tags: scala

I have a map like below

```
t: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col3 -> val3, col2 -> val2, col5 -> val5, col1 -> val1, col4 -> val4)
```

I want to get the keys and values in 2 array variables in a single iteration so that the key/values
go in the same order.

The below assignment doesn't seem to work

```
val x,y = for{ (x,y) <- t } yield (x,y)

x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col3 -> val3, col2 -> val2, col5 -> val5, col1 -> val1, col4 -> val4)
y: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col3 -> val3, col2 -> val2, col5 -> val5, col1 -> val1, col4 -> val4)
```

what I want is

```
x:List[String] = List(col3 , col2 , col5 , col1 , col4 )
y:List[String] = List(val3 , val2 , val5 , val1 , val4 )
```

How to get it?.

Comment: As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#unzip[A1,A2](implicitasPair:A=%3E(A1,A2)):(CC[A1],CC[A2])) is your friend: `val (x, y) = t.unzip`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez.. yes, right.. :-(

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding solution yourself and accepting it, or delete the question.

Comment: Leo added a solution.. and itis not there now.. will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer as requested by Tomer.

```
val (x, y) = t.unzip
```

works